# statsmodels heteroscedasticity breusch pagan test doesn't match

Tags: python, statsmodels

When I estimate the breach-pagan test step by step doesn't math with the bp value in statsmodels:

[image]

[Here is link to the nb](https://github.com/mmngreco/AE_unizar/blob/master/caso2.1.ipynb) in spanish.

I have been tested in Gretl and my 'manual' estimation is correct, but I want to know why is the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Koenker version in Gretl.

I don't find a Gretl reference right now, but according to the unit tests, the version in statsmodels is equal to the Koenker version of the Breusch-Pagan test.

I don't see an option for the original Breusch-Pagan test, but that one is not robust to non-normality (assumption on 4th moment, IIRC).

In general, many of the Lagrange multiplier specification tests have several versions that are asymptotically equivalent but differ in small samples, for example statsmodels reports LM test and the F-test version. Additionally, they differ which extra assumptions are required for their validity.

For example statsmodels does not have yet a heteroscedasticity test that is robust to autocorrelation. There are again several versions and I have not seen them available as standard option in any package yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! sorry for delay, I have been looking for Koenker test in Gretl but I don't find any mention about it.  The next step is try the Koenker version test to corroborate.

Comment: I have implemented the koenker version as you suggest, and I get the same result, so thanks again.